# Cucumber TestRunner class returning steps as undefined

Tags: cucumber, test-runner

I am running cucumber for the first time and created feature file, step definitions and added maven dependencies.However, after running testRunner,Cucumber is returning undefined steps when run from test Runner package.Here is the testRun class under testRunner package:

```
package testRunner;

import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions
(       tags= {"@tag","@tag1"},
        features= "./Features/orangeHRM.feature",
        glue= "stepDefinitions.steps",
        dryRun=true,
        monochrome=true ,//removes unnecessary characters from console
        plugin= {"pretty","html:test-output"}
        )
public class testRun {

}
```

Here is the POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>cucumber_test</groupId>
  <artifactId>cucumber_test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  
<dependencies>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>7.12.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>7.12.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.12</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
                <version>7.12.1</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.5</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-jvm -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.5</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

            
            
 
            <dependency>
                <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.5</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.sourceforge.cobertura</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.5</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
                <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2-beta</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.4</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
                <version>6.9.9</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.5</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
    

            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
                <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.0</version>
                <scope>system</scope>
                <systemPath>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-20.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools-1.8.0.jar</systemPath>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
                <version>3.14.0</version>
            </dependency> 



</dependencies>
</project>
```

I have created package testRunner under src/test/java. So, it like src/test/Java--->testRunner--->testRun class
However, when I run the feature file it is getting executed without any issues.

Comment: Can you show your full project structure starting from project root? Also do your scenarios contain tags?